Mapping arrays of objects conditionally in Javascript
I have array of objects with a multi-level nesting.
const switches = [{
  orgId: "1111a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
  orgName: "Management 1",
  orgType: 2,
  organisations: [],
  features: [{
    name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }, {
    name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }],
}, {
  orgId: "2222a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
  orgName: "Management 2",
  orgType: 2,
  organisations: [{
    orgId: "33333f59a-4976-11ed-af5d-021feb88a3f6",
    orgName: "Submanagement ",
    orgType: 2,
    features: [{
      name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
      type: "feature",
      category: "Management Features",
      value: false,
    }, {
      name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
      type: "feature",
      category: "Management Features",
      value: false,
    }],
  }],
  features: [{
    name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }, {
    name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }],
}, {
  orgId: "4444a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
  orgName: "Management 3",
  orgType: 2,
  organisations: [],
  features: [{
    name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }, {
    name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
    type: "feature",
    category: "Management Features",
    value: false,
  }],
}];

What I want is the function to map it to new array where if the string provided === name in features array objects then value should be changed to the value provided in parameter.
So if I call the function like
handleTopLevelToggle('AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels', true);

I should return the same nested arrays but with value changed to true for all the with name 'AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels', on all nested levels.
Te solution I've started with was
const handleTopLevelToggle = (value, fSwitch) => {
  const mappedArray = switches.map((swtch) => {
    swtch.features.map((feature) => {
      if (feature.name === fSwitch) {
        return { ...swtch, value: value };
      }
      return swtch;
    });
  });

  return mappedArray;
};


Your current solution is on the right track, but it has a few issues.

You are not returning anything from the outer map function, which
will result in undefined values in your mappedArray.
You are not
handling the nested organisations array.
You are replacing the entire swtch object with a new value, instead of just updating the value property of the matching feature.

Revised Function:
const handleTopLevelToggle = (fSwitch: string, value: boolean) => {
  const mapFeatures = (features) => {
    return features.map((feature) => {
      if (feature.name === fSwitch) {
        return { ...feature, value: value };
      }
      return feature;
    });
  };

  const mapOrganisations = (organisations) => {
    return organisations.map((org) => {
      return { ...org, features: mapFeatures(org.features) };
    });
  };

  const mappedArray = switches.map((swtch) => {
    return {
      ...swtch,
      features: mapFeatures(swtch.features),
      organisations: mapOrganisations(swtch.organisations),
    };
  });

  return mappedArray;
};


This is the most intuitive solution of all. Thanks.

You just need a simple recursive function:
const handleTopLevelToggle = (data, name, value) => {
  const toggle = (organisations) => organisations?.map((o) => ({
    ...o,
    features: o.features.map((f) => ({
      ...f,
      value: f.name === name ? value : f.value
    })),
    organisations: toggle(o.organisations)
  }));
  return toggle(data);
};


Complete snippet:


const switches = [
  {
    orgId: "1111a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
    orgName: "Management 1",
    orgType: 2,
    organisations: [],
    features: [
      {
        name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
      {
        name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    orgId: "2222a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
    orgName: "Management 2",
    orgType: 2,
    organisations: [
      {
        orgId: "33333f59a-4976-11ed-af5d-021feb88a3f6",
        orgName: "Submanagement ",
        orgType: 2,
        features: [
          {
            name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
            type: "feature",
            category: "Management Features",
            value: false,
          },
          {
            name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
            type: "feature",
            category: "Management Features",
            value: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    features: [
      {
        name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
      {
        name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    orgId: "4444a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d",
    orgName: "Management 3",
    orgType: 2,
    organisations: [],
    features: [
      {
        name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
      {
        name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole",
        type: "feature",
        category: "Management Features",
        value: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const handleTopLevelToggle = (data, name, value) => {
  const toggle = (organisations) => organisations?.map((o) => ({
    ...o,
    features: o.features.map((f) => ({
      ...f,
      value: f.name === name ? value : f.value
    })),
    organisations: toggle(o.organisations)
  }));
  return toggle(data);
};

console.log(handleTopLevelToggle(switches, 'AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels', true));




You could use a recursive approach and have a look to arrays as values.


const
    switches = [{ orgId: "1111a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d", orgName: "Management 1", orgType: 2, organisations: [], features: [{ name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }, { name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }] }, { orgId: "2222a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d", orgName: "Management 2", orgType: 2, organisations: [{ orgId: "33333f59a-4976-11ed-af5d-021feb88a3f6", orgName: "Submanagement ", orgType: 2, features: [{ name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }, { name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }] }], features: [{ name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }, { name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }] }, { orgId: "4444a7cd-0d58-11ef-83a2-06a19a0b1f5d", orgName: "Management 3", orgType: 2, organisations: [], features: [{ name: "AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }, { name: "AdminCategoryApprovalByRole", type: "feature", category: "Management Features", value: false }] }],
    change = (array, name, value) => array.map(object => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => [
            k,
            Array.isArray(v)
                ? change(v, name, value)
                :  k === 'value' && object.name === name
                    ? value
                    : v
        ])
    )),
    result = change(switches, 'AdvancedAdminApprovalLevels', true);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




Depending on what needs to be changed the solution will differ. E.g. for a shallow change (all object references will stay the same) you could go with
function changeAllFor(object:any, key:string,value:any){
    if(!object)return;
    if(Array.isArray(object)){
        for(let i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
            changeAllFor(object[i], key, value);
        }
        return;
    }
    if(typeof object !== 'object')return;
    const keys = Object.keys(object);
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        if(keys[i] === key){
            object[keys[i]] = value;
        }
        if(typeof object[keys[i]] === 'object'){
            changeAllFor(object[keys[i]], key, value);
        }
    }
}

If you need new object references (e.g. for a compare on object level) i'd go with:
function createNewFor(object,key,value){
    if(!object)return object; //undefined or null
    if(Array.isArray(object)){
        return object.map((item) => createNewFor(item, key, value));
    }
    if(typeof object !== 'object')return object;
    const keys = Object.keys(object);
    const newObject = {...object};
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        if(keys[i] === key){
            newObject[keys[i]] = value;
        }else{
            newObject[keys[i]] = createNewFor(object[keys[i]], key, value);
        }
    }
}

